# Orbeon preselect autocomplete value in reusable component

Tags: orbeon

I'm using Orbeon v2017.1 and I'm trying to create a service within a *Section Template* which is supposed to retrieve the label of the default country which should be preselected in an autocomplete field (country).

I want to preselect the country only if the user has not entered a value (or, when the form loads). It should support multiple languages.

If I trigger the action after "form loads" and after "the controls are ready", it calls my service but only for the *library* form. For all other forms which include this reusable section, the service is not called.

Is there some other way this could be achieved? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Below is an example of an autocomplete field, service, and action which sets the control value

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude">
<xh:head>
    <xh:title/>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">

                 <xf:instance id="all-countries"
                     src="http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso/ListOfCountryNamesByName/XML"/>

        <!-- Main instance -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <country-dynamic-autocomplete label=""/>


                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Bindings -->
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">
                <xf:bind id="country-dynamic-autocomplete-bind" ref="country-dynamic-autocomplete"
                         name="country-dynamic-autocomplete"/>


            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>

        <!-- Metadata -->
        <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>insurance</application-name>
                <form-name>test</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en"/>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- Attachments -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>

        <!-- All form resources -->
        <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <country-dynamic-autocomplete>
                        <label>Countries Preselect Value</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </country-dynamic-autocomplete>

                    <section-1>
                        <label>Country Section</label>
                    </section-1>

                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>

        <xf:instance id="get-default-country-value-instance" class="fr-service"
                     xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                    <body xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                  xmlns:fbf="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.FormBuilder">&lt;params/&gt;</body>
                </xf:instance>
        <xf:submission id="get-default-country-value-submission" class="fr-service"
                       resource="http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso/CountryName/XML/debug?sCountryISOCode=DE"
                       method="get"
                       serialization="none"
                       mediatype="none"/>
        <xf:action id="set-country-default-value-binding">
            <xf:action event="DOMActivate" ev:observer="country-dynamic-autocomplete-control"
                       if="true()">
                <xf:send submission="get-default-country-value-submission"/>
            </xf:action>
            <xf:action event="xforms-submit" ev:observer="get-default-country-value-submission">
                <xf:var name="request-instance-name" value="'get-default-country-value-instance'"/>
                <xf:action/>
            </xf:action>
            <xf:action event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="get-default-country-value-submission">
                <xf:action class="fr-set-control-value-action">
                    <xf:var name="control-name" value="'country-dynamic-autocomplete'"/>
                    <xf:var name="control-value" value="/string"/>


                </xf:action>
            </xf:action>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                 xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <fr:autocomplete xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                                             xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                             id="country-dynamic-autocomplete-control"
                                             labelref="@label"
                                             max-results-displayed="300"
                                             resource="http://webservices.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso/ListOfCountryNamesByName/XML"
                                             bind="country-dynamic-autocomplete-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/country-dynamic-autocomplete/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/country-dynamic-autocomplete/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>


                                <xf:itemset ref="/ArrayOftCountryCodeAndName/tCountryCodeAndName">
                                    <xf:label ref="sName"/>
                                    <xf:value ref="sISOCode"/>
                                </xf:itemset>
                            </fr:autocomplete>

                        </xh:td>

                    </xh:tr>

                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
```

**EDIT 2 (new service):**

```
<xh:html xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
     xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
     xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude">     
<xh:head>         
    <xh:title/>         
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">                      
        <xf:instance id="all-countries" src="http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/"/>                   
        <!-- Main instance -->             <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xxf:index="id">                 
            <form>                     
                <section-1>                         
                    <country-dynamic-autocomplete label=""/>
                    <control-3/>                                                                       
                </section-1>                 
            </form>             
        </xf:instance>              
        <!-- Bindings -->             <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds" ref="instance('fr-form-instance')">                 
            <xf:bind id="section-1-bind" name="section-1" ref="section-1">                     
                <xf:bind id="country-dynamic-autocomplete-bind" ref="country-dynamic-autocomplete"
                         name="country-dynamic-autocomplete"/>
                <xf:bind id="control-3-bind" ref="control-3" name="control-3" xxf:whitespace="trim"/>                                                           
            </xf:bind>             
        </xf:bind>              
        <!-- Metadata -->             <xf:instance xxf:readonly="true" id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">                 
            <metadata>                     
                <application-name>insurance</application-name>                     
                <form-name>test</form-name>                     
                <title xml:lang="en"/>                     
                <description xml:lang="en"/>                 
            </metadata>             
        </xf:instance>              
        <!-- Attachments -->             <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">                 
            <attachments>                     
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>                     
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>                 
            </attachments>             
        </xf:instance>              
        <!-- All form resources -->             <!-- Don't make readonly by default in case a service modifies the resources -->             <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">                 
            <resources>                     
                <resource xml:lang="en">                         
                    <country-dynamic-autocomplete>                             
                        <label>Countries Preselect Value</label>                             
                        <hint/>                         
                    </country-dynamic-autocomplete>
                    <control-3>
                        <label>XML</label>
                        <hint/>
                    </control-3>                                                  
                    <section-1>                             
                        <label>Country Section</label>                         
                    </section-1>                                              
                </resource>                 
            </resources>             
        </xf:instance>              
        <xf:instance id="get-default-country-value-instance" class="fr-service"
                     xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">                         
            <body xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                  xmlns:fbf="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.FormBuilder">&lt;params/&gt;</body>                     
        </xf:instance>             
        <xf:submission id="get-default-country-value-submission" class="fr-service"
                       resource="http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/deutschland"
                       method="get"
                       serialization="none"
                       mediatype="none"/>                      
        <xf:instance id="json-to-xml-instance" class="fr-service" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                    <body xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                  xmlns:fbf="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.FormBuilder">&lt;params/&gt;</body>
                </xf:instance>
        <xf:submission id="json-to-xml-submission" class="fr-service"
                       resource="http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
                       method="get"
                       serialization="none"
                       mediatype="none"/>
        <xf:action id="show-json-in-xml-binding">
            <xf:action event="fr-run-form-load-action-after-controls" ev:observer="fr-form-model"
                       if="true()">
                <xf:send submission="json-to-xml-submission"/>
            </xf:action>
            <xf:action event="xforms-submit" ev:observer="json-to-xml-submission">
                <xf:var name="request-instance-name" value="'json-to-xml-instance'"/>
                <xf:action/>
            </xf:action>
            <xf:action event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="json-to-xml-submission">
                <xf:action class="fr-set-control-value-action">
                    <xf:var name="control-name" value="'control-3'"/>
                    <xf:var name="control-value" value="saxon:serialize(., 'xml')"/>
                </xf:action>
            </xf:action>
        </xf:action>
        <xf:action id="set-country-default-value-binding">                 
            <xf:action event="DOMActivate" ev:observer="country-dynamic-autocomplete-control"
                       if="true()">                     
                <xf:send submission="get-default-country-value-submission"/>                 
            </xf:action>                 
            <xf:action event="xforms-submit" ev:observer="get-default-country-value-submission">                     
                <xf:var name="request-instance-name" value="'get-default-country-value-instance'"/>                     
                <xf:action/>                 
            </xf:action>                 
            <xf:action event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="get-default-country-value-submission">                     
                <xf:action class="fr-set-control-value-action">
                    <xf:var name="control-name" value="'country-dynamic-autocomplete'"/>
                    <xf:var name="control-value" value="saxon:serialize(., 'xml')"/>
                </xf:action>                 
            </xf:action>             
        </xf:action>
    </xf:model>     
</xh:head>     
<xh:body>         
    <fr:view>             
        <fr:body xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl" xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
                 xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">                 
            <fr:section id="section-1-control" bind="section-1-bind">                     
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>                     
                <fr:grid>                         
                    <xh:tr>                             
                        <xh:td>                                 
                            <fr:autocomplete xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
                                             xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                                             id="country-dynamic-autocomplete-control"
                                             labelref="@label"
                                             max-results-displayed="300"
                                             resource="http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
                                             bind="country-dynamic-autocomplete-bind">                                     
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/country-dynamic-autocomplete/label"/>                                     
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/country-dynamic-autocomplete/hint"/>                                     
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>                                                                                       
                                <xf:itemset ref="/_/name">                                         
                                    <xf:label ref="name"/>                                         
                                    <xf:value ref="alpha2Code"/>                                     
                                </xf:itemset>                                 
                            </fr:autocomplete>                                                              
                        </xh:td>                                                      
                    </xh:tr>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:input id="control-3-control" bind="control-3-bind">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-3/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-3/hint"/>

                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xf:input>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>                                              
                </fr:grid>                 
            </fr:section>             
        </fr:body>         
    </fr:view>     
</xh:body> 
</xh:html>
```

Comment: Hi Masha, are you saying that the service is used to initialize an autocomplete in the section template, and that when you publish and run the library form the autocomplete is properly initialized, but that it isn't when the section is included in another form?

Comment: Hi avernet, the service is meant to be called in order to select the default country in the autocomplete field. When testing, the service was called only when the library form loaded, and not when other forms which included the reusable section were loaded

Comment: Mmh… the service should also get called when the section template is being used in other forms. Let's try to narrow down this problem. Is it specific to the autocomplete? I.e. are you having it also when using a text field? Next, can you create an example which as simple as you can that reproduces the problem, using a public service, and add to your question, so we can see what goes wrong?

Comment: Hi Avernet, I have added an example to the posted question, thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you @masha.knezevic for the example, but as for your [other question about the static autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52042578/orbeon-static-autocomplete-not-working), I'm unable to run it as `http://webservices.oorsprong.org/` is returning a 503 for me at the moment. Hopefully you can get this service to work, or update it to use another publicly available service.

Comment: Hi avernet, the service doesn't work for me anymore either.
I have found two more, but can't seem to get them working.
The first one http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/ returns the list of countries, but I can't add wb:country to the element, label and value for the autocomplete - is this possible somehow?
The second one http://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all returns the list of countries as a json, but for some reason I can't populate the autocomplete.

I'll update the question with this xml. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use `*` in place of the prefix. It will match all names, whatever namespace they are are in, but this is fine for a test. For instance, with the list of countries you linked to, you can run `count(/*:countries/*:country)`, which returns 50. You'll let me know when you got a chance to update your example accordingly.